# Assigning data to a specific user using SQL/VisualStudio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm creating an app with Visual Studio and connecting it to SQL.

I have two sets of data in SQL along with two usernames and passwords.

Is there anyway of assigning data to a specific user or am I trying the impossible?

Example when User1 logs in to the app on Visual Studio, they should only view/edit their data.
But when User2 logs in, he should only view the second set of data.

Currently, when they log in using the username and password, they both can see all the data. I have one central window the login form takes them to, and then they add/edit/view data.

Comment: Visual studio is a gui to program so you will not log in there, probably your app will log into mysql. But even then you must mark the data by referenzing , to which uiser which data belongs, but we see neither code nor your data structure

Comment: If i understand what your are loking for you have to implement this model (Data Model Pattern) : https://tdan.com/a-universal-person-and-organization-data-model/5014

Comment: @Shadow, I'm using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with Row Level Security in the database - [check it out here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259view=sql-server-ver15)